# How to make a gestureRecogniser selector work in swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, selector

Below is the code I have been using to try and add a gesture recogniser to something. I am getting the yellow error: "No method declared with objective C selector dragging" and then the program is crashing when I go to pan on it. The code and way of using a selector seems to work in all tutorials but it's the problem here.

```
    class GameViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let p = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector("dragging"))
        p.delegate = self
        characterGridView!.addGestureRecognizer(p)
    }

    func dragging(p: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        print("works")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect.

Change

```
let p = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector("dragging"))
```

to

```
let p = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dragging(p:)))
```